# ngbPopover autoClose isn't a known property of div

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using an ngbPopover that is displayed when a user clicks on a div. When I try to add the [autoClose]="true" property to the div I get the error:

Can't bind to 'autoClose' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

The div is inside an ng-template. This is my code:

```
<ng-template #eventTemplate let-weekEvent="weekEvent">
  <div placement="right" [ngbPopover]="popoverContentTemplate" [autoClose]="true" popoverTitle="Event"
    container="body">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Which version of ng-bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I`m using 2.2.0

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api: the documentation of autoClose says: *since 3.0.0*

Comment: This indeed was the problem. Thanks for directing me to that, somehow I`ve missed it